# Upload file from mobile phone sends application/octet-stream

Tags: php, android, file

I have a simple form with video file upload. It works on regular PC, but when uploading from a mobile device (Android), it sends the file mime type as `application/octet-stream` with file `null` and error 1.

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

here is the form

```
<input type="file" id="video_link" name="video[link]" class="form-control" accept="video/*">
```

here is var_dump of video submitted on mobile

```
UploadedFile {#9 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "VID-20160712-WA0029.mp4"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -size: 0
  -error: 1
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath1970: "/app/web"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: -01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

here is uploaded file dump from regular pc browser

```
VideoController.php on line 59:
UploadedFile {#14 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "videoplayback.mp4"
  -mimeType: "video/mp4"
  -size: 684535
  -error: 0
  path: "C:\wamp\tmp"
  filename: "phpC612.tmp"
  basename: "phpC612.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\wamp\tmp\phpC612.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\wamp\tmp\phpC612.tmp"
  aTime: 2016-07-14 05:43:25
  mTime: 2016-07-14 05:43:25
  cTime: 2016-07-14 05:43:25
  inode: 0
  size: 684535
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
        linkTarget:"C:\wamp\tmp\phpC612.tmp"}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Ok just edited thank you

Comment: What if you remove the `accept="video/*"` , and try to upload a JPG or another file?

Comment: no I put that in there thinking it will make a difference but it doesn't. either I remove it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help.

According to [HTML form enctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp):

> **multipart/form-data:** No characters are encoded. This value is **required** when you are using forms that have a file upload control

Make sure, that your `form` element has attribute `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data`.